# Can you set local variables through system calls?

Tags: c, scope, signals

I have one program that forks other programs. When the forked programs receive SIGUSR2, a variable in them is supposed to change. I'm not sure how to do that because that variable isn't in the scope of the function that SIGUSR2 calls.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a function can not see/manipulate the value of a variable local to another function (ignoring the possibility of a visible pointer pointing to a local variable which is either static or in an active call frame).

Answer (score 0):

Your question's setup is not very clear, but to answer generically (and perhaps a bit pedantically), code does not change variables, code changes memory.

That is... a variable is simply a convenient way to refer to a memory location. "Changing a variable" is really just changing the value at its position in memory. This is relevant because while it's very convenient to execute `x = 5;`, that's not the only way to change `x`. Any code that knows where `x` lives in memory, and has permission to write to that location, may therefore change `x`.

In your specific case you're starting a second process. Initially this second process has a copy of the memory of the first one, letting it read the same data, but it's typical that any post-fork changes to memory are only visible in the process that made the change.

Your wording suggests that you're not only calling `fork()`, but that you may also then be exec'ing to another program altogether... making even the copy of the parent's memory go away.

In short, what you're trying to do is probably not possible without going through some rather ugly hacks, and it would definitely be worth finding a different solution (such as shared memory).

Comment: I took his question to mean that both the SIGUSR2 handler and the local variable were at least in the same process.  This may have been a poor assumption.

Comment: You may be right - in which case the OP is guilty of providing more information than is germane to the information needed while also not providing enough information about what s/he's trying to do ;)